# preg_match_all not fetching image src from file in php

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I have page image.php

where images are kept in container like below :- Note: There are other Images outside container div too.. i just want images from container div.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title>Image Holder</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://examepl.com/logo.png"></a>
            <div id="side">
                <div id="facebook"><img src="http://examepl.com/fb.png"></div>
                <div id="twiiter"><img src="http://examepl.com/t.png"></div>
                <div id="gplus"><img src="http://examepl.com/gp.png"></div>
            </div>
        </header>      
        <div class="container">
            <p>SOme Post</p>
            <img src="http://examepl.com/some.png" title="some image" />

            <p>SOme Post</p>
            <img src="http://examepl.com/some.png" title="some image" />

            <p>SOme Post</p>
            <img src="http://examepl.com/some.png" title="some image" />
        </div>
        <footer>
            <div id="foot">
                copyright &copy; 2013
            </div>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

and i am trying to fetch only image from my image.php file with preg_match_all, but it returns boolean(false) :(

my php code :-

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents("image.php");
preg_match_all("/<div class=\"container\">(.*?)</div>/", $file, $match);
preg_match_all("/<img src=\"(.*?)\">/", $match, $images);

var_dump($images);
?>
```

Both the files are in root folder , and now i am getting blank page :(

Any help would be great

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily obtain what you want with an XPath query:

```
$url = 'http://examepl.com/image.php';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$srcs = $xpath->query("//div[@class='container']//img/attribute::src");
foreach ($srcs as $src) {
    echo '<br/>' . $src->value; 
}
```

Comment: i have another domain who will also need to fetch images from my first domain too... and i dont want to write different code for my both the sites..

Comment: @DragonSnake: It's not a problem, write a function with the filename as argument.

Comment: well i replaced `@$doc->loadHTMLFile('image.php');` with this `@$doc->loadHTMLFile($file);` where my $file is http://examepl.com/image.php and it returned blank image :(

Comment: @DragonSnake: you don't need to use file_get_contents, see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

You better not use regex for this purpose. PHP provides nice DOM api for this purpose. Consider code like below:

```
$html = <<< EOF
<div class="container">
<p>SOme Post</p>
<img src="http://examepl.com/some1.png" title="some image" />
<p>SOme Post</p>
<img src="http://examepl.com/some2.png" title="some image" />
<p>SOme Post</p>
<img src="http://examepl.com/some3.png" title="some image" />
</div>
EOF;
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($html); // loads your html
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$nodelist = $xpath->query("//div[@class='container']/img");
$img = array();
for($i=0; $i < $nodelist->length; $i++) {
    $node = $nodelist->item($i);
    $img[] = $node->getAttribute('src');
}
print_r($img);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://examepl.com/some1.png
    [1] => http://examepl.com/some2.png
    [2] => http://examepl.com/some3.png
)
```

#### Live Demo: http://ideone.com/iBhVMF

Comment: i have 2 domain, and i might have to use http://www.examepl.com/image.php to fetch image in my another domain :(

Comment: You can use your `$file` variable to load DOM like this: `$doc->loadHTML($file);`

Comment: i tried your code for $file in http://examepl.com/image.php and it returned `Array( )` :(

Comment: Can you post HTML content held in `$file` variable.

Comment: I took the `image.php` posted by you in your question and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work for you try the link below to test your regex

```
preg_match_all("/<div class=\"container\">(.*?)<\/div>/", $file, $match);
preg_match_all("/<img .*?(?=src)src=\"([^\"]+)\"/", $match[1][0], $images);
```

[http://www.phpliveregex.com](http://www.phpliveregex.com/)

Comment: it returns blank page :(

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all("/<img src=\"(.*?)\">/", $match, $images);
```

replace with

```
preg_match_all("/<img src=\"(.*?)\"/", $match, $images); // stripped ">" char
```

Comment: not fetching image, it says array[2] 0 =>array[0] => {} array[1] => {}  :(

Comment: Can you post the contents of image.php? If there's a loop displaying images - it won't work as the file_get_contents will get the php code, not the output for browsers ;)